# RoR -- NoMethodError: private method `open' called for Gem::Package:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hey does anyone know what this error message means? I installed ruby from source then proceeded to install rubygems, and then installed rails via `gem install rails`

After creating a new project, I did a `bundle install` and got this error:

> mark@mark-laptop:~/guide/first_app$ sudo bundle install Fetching
>   source index for https://rubygems.org/
>
> NoMethodError: private method `open' called for Gem::Package:Class An
>   error occured while installing rake (0.9.2.2), and Bundler cannot
>   continue. Make sure that`gem install rake -v '0.9.2.2'` succeeds
>   before bundling.

I did that command (`gem install rake -v '0.9.2.2'`) and it worked fine.. I'm rather confused

Answer (score 8):

Try `gem install bundler` to install/update bundler after installing/updating rubygems.

It worked for me when I had your problem.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a bug in the master branch of rubygems from GitHub. If you grab an archive of 1.8.24 from http://rubygems.org/pages/download instead, everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I have rubygems 2.0.3 and I get the same error. I deleted gemfile.lock file in the project. Only change I got in error is 
From
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '0.9.2.2'` succeeds before bundling.
Changed to 
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.0.3'` succeeds before bundling.
The new gem install rake also worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that you are using different ruby versions and gems when running commands with and without sudo. You can try running

```
sudo ruby -v
```

and

```
ruby -v
```

In addition you can check for different gem paths

```
gem env
```

and

```
sudo gem env
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. gem update --system
> 2. gem install bundler