# NoMethodError when creating new Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

I have this error when I'm creating a new Rails folder (with `rails new my_app`) :

http://cl.ly/image/3S071x1l0w3J

```
-> NoMethodError: private method 'open' called for Gem::Package:Class
An error occured while installing rake (10.0.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that 'gem install rake -v '10.0.3' succeeds before bundling.
```

Any help please?

Comment: Have you tried running the suggested command (`gem install rake -v '10.0.3'`)? If yes, what is the output?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem with the version of rubygems : [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203945/ror-nomethoderror-private-method-open-called-for-gempackageclass)

Try updating with the following command :

```
gem update --system
```